# Pictures taken after first shot have low lighting

Tags: android, android-camera

I am taking pics on android 4.4 using code from here  [1]: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html "4. Tutorial: Using the camera API" and using Eclipse "Full Screen activity" as template.

The first picture is normal, but after that the **subsequent pictures are too dark to be useful.**

I searched SO but couldn't fix it. What am I doing wrong here ?

My MainActivity Class

```
/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
  *
  * @see SystemUiHider
  */
 public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
static final String DEBUG_TAG = "fsym";
static String fileName = "";
private Camera camera;
private int cameraId = 0;
static long numPics = 1;
private TextView results;
private ImageView displayArea;
float dpHeight, dpWidth;

/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
 * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
 */
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

/**
 * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
 */
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

/**
 * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "onCreate called");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;


    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTxtBox);
    displayArea = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePanel);
    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider.setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
        // Cached values.
        int mControlsHeight;
        int mShortAnimTime;

        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                // screen.
                if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                    mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                }
                if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                    mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                }
                controlsView.animate().translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight).setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
            } else {
                // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                // controls.
                controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                // Schedule a hide().
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
        }
    });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.takePicBtn).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    results.setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

    // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "onPostCreate called");
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiUpdateRunnable.run();
    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);       
}

/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "delayedHide called");
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}

Handler uiUpdatehandler = new Handler();
Runnable uiUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (fileName!=null && fileName.trim().length()>0){
        displayArea.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName));
        displayArea.setRotation(-90);
        displayArea.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        }       

        results.setText("Ratio:"+FaceAnalyzer.measureFace(fileName));
        //results.invalidate();     
        //displayArea.invalidate(); 
        uiUpdatehandler.postDelayed(uiUpdateRunnable,1000);
    }
};


public void takePicture(View view){
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "takePicture called");
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));                                  
}

public void quitApp(View view){
    uiUpdatehandler.removeCallbacks(uiUpdateRunnable);
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "findFrontfacingCamera called");
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }

@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "onPause called");
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
```

}

My PhotoHandler:

```
public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

  private final Context context;

  public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Photohandler contstructor called");
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "onPicturetaken called");
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
      Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;

    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date +"_" +DashboardActivity.numPics+".jpg";

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "New Image saved:" + photoFile);
      DashboardActivity.fileName = filename;
      DashboardActivity.numPics++;

    } catch (Exception error) {
      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
          + error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  private File getDir() {
      Log.d(DashboardActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "getDir called");  
    File sdDir = Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "FacialSymmetryAnalyzer");
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?